# How can I pass a bunch of data to my computer when debugging in Android?

Tags: android, debugging

Log.d isn't sufficient for pushing a bunch of image data.  Is there an easy way to do this?  I could write a file, but then I'd have to switch my phone into USB mode, copy the file over, and then switch it back...

Comment: Do you want to write it in your own created file or in logs itself ? Does not your question and title seem contradictory?

Comment: Can you please share what exactly you are doing and what you want, so that someone can give meaningful suggestion.

Comment: I don't think I contradicted myself.  I simply want to get a lot of data (any kind really) from my phone to my computer.  The logs are ill-suited (and not meant for) this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I could write a file, but then I'd have to switch my phone into USB mode, copy the file over, and then switch it back

You can use `adb pull` or ADT to fetch the file from the phone's file system.

```
adb pull <remote> <local>
```

From ADT, use the File Explorer tab in DDMS perspective.

[image: Pull file using ADT]

Having said that, most probably there is a way to debug without having to jump through hoops of creating the file, fetching it on the computer and then analyzing it.